# C++/CLI завершение работы консольного приложения

Tags: c++-cli

Есть функция Main. В ней я могу в любое время завершить работу приложения вызвав `return 0;`

А как мне сделать это из другой функции? Точнее даже из функции класса. Пока что пришло в голову только вызывать исключение и обрабатывать его в мэйне, вызывая `return 0;`. Хотя я не уверен, что это сработает. Вроде бы в блоке *Catch* нельзя возвращать значение. В любом случае мне это не нравится.

Comment: `exit(0)` пробовали?

Comment: @kff, нет такого.

Comment: iRumba, видимо, вы не там искали :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так скажите где искать? у меня тут управляемый код.

Comment: iRumba, в своем ответе я дал ссылку на документацию. Там, среди прочего, указан заголовочный файл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В блоке `catch` **можно** возвращать значение, так что придуманный вами вариант сработает.

Кроме того, есть библиотечная функция [`exit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) из стандартной библиотеки языка C++.

Еще если библиотечная функция [`System.Enviroment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) из CLR

Наконец, в WinAPI есть функция [`ExitProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx)

Но, вообще говоря, выход из программы откуда попало - антипаттерн. Возможно, вам следует пересмотреть архитектуру приложения.

Comment: `System.Enviroment.Exit` - то что нужно!